# Умножение нескольких переменных с отрицательными значениями

Tags: java

Даны несколько переменных не связанные друг с другом, надо обнаружить, какие из переменных имеют отрицательные значения и умножить их между собой. Как это можно реализовать? Массивами пользоваться нельзя.

Comment: где обнаружить? О_о

Comment: Ну, у нас изначально есть переменные, имеющие значения, среди них есть отрицательные, и их собственно надо умножить между собой

Comment: делай либо массив, либо список. Просто по переменным шариться невозможно......точнее можно рефлексией. но думаю это не то, что нужно на твоём уровне знания.....а работать с массивом и найти там отрицательные числа - проще пареной репы

Comment: просто нам запретили массивами пользоваться, а строка, не знаю

Comment: Можно и через строку.....в цикле пробегаешься по символам, приводишь к числу....смотришь что оно меньше нуля...и умножаешь

Comment: "Даны несколько переменных" - где даны? В каком виде?

Comment: а что за список? впервые слышу, новичок просто :)

Comment: List.....но если массивы нельзя, то и списки вряд ли.... так что работай со строкой посимвольно в цикле

Comment: самые обычные переменные по типу a=1 b=232

Comment: @siarhei987 возможно. но автор - шпиЁн, и не хочет говорить все детали))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский простите, какие еще подробности нужны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятна формулировка, но, вероятно, вы хотите что-то такое:

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
int c = ...;
int d = ...;

int product = 1;
if (a < 0) product = product * a;
if (b < 0) product = product * b;
if (c < 0) product = product * c;
if (d < 0) product = product * d;
```

Comment: Просто нам такое задание дали, не знаю что еще можно сюда добавить, простите

Comment: Ну вот, берите тогда каждую переменную, проверяйте на отрицательность и домножайте в общее произведение.

Comment: спасибо за ответ