# Определить знак введенного числа, затем сложить положительные числа

Tags: python

```
a = int(input()) #пользователь вводит число от (-бесконечность;бесконечность)
b = int(input()) #пользователь вводит число от (-бесконечность;бесконечность)
c = int(input()) #пользователь вводит число от (-бесконечность;бесконечность)
if 0 < a:
    plus1 = a
elif 0 > a:
    minus1 = a
elif 0 < b:
    plus2 = b
elif 0 > b:
    minus2 = b
elif 0 < c:
    plus3 = c
elif 0 > c:
    minus3 = c #цикл определяет знак числа
else:
    plus1 = a
    plus2 = b
    plus3 = c
    print(plus1 + plus2 + plus3) #сложение положительных чисел
```

Проблема в том, что когда я ввожу цифры, то числа не складываются.

Comment: задание из курса "Поколение Python": курс для начинающих на stepik. нужно чтобы код определил знак введенного числа, затем сложил числа, которые являются положительными

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1420557/178576

Comment: Присвойте сначала всем переменным 0, иначе они будут не определены при проходе по каким-то веткам кода.

Comment: Сандал, вы пишите, что вы хотите? А то есть некая команда в заголовке и потом  код. И что? Если он не работает, то приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вашей программы заключается в том, что когда ваше первое введенное число (`a`) будет например *положительным*, **выполнится только первая команда** (`plus1 = a`) и весь остальной код будет проигнорирован.

Почему проигнорирован?

Потому, что вся ваша программа **состоит только из ветвей одного и того-же самого `if`,** и во всяком случае может исполниться *только код одной ветви.*

---

Как это исправить?

- Для всякого введенного числа (`a`, `b`, `c`) используйте **отдельный** `if`, т.к. эти числа независимы друг от друга.
- Переменные `minus1`, `minus2`, `minus3` совсем не нужны, но
- нужно сначала переменным `plus1`, `plus2`, `plus3` присвоить нуль.
- Ваше заключительное `else` надо тем самым удалить.

```
plus1 = plus2 = plus3 = 0

if 0 < a:
    plus1 = a
if 0 < b:
    plus2 = b
if 0 < c:
    plus3 = c
    
print(plus1 + plus2 + plus3) #сложение положительных чисел
```